# OpenSSL: is it possible to attach extra string for authentication?

Tags: authentication, ssl, openssl

For certificate authentication, when a certificate is being sent to the remote side is it possible to attach an extra string, such that the certificate will be displayed along with the special string?

The idea proposed for my project is: A creates a random string, A sends the random string along with its certificate to B, A sends the random string via different media to B, finally B sees the certificate and also compares the string to authenticate A.

Anyway, the fundamental problem is: A and B do not share common in their certificate verification path, and they still want mutual authentication.

Although the proposed one is implementable, I don't know how to reduce the amount of work by leveraging available OpenSSL API's more efficiently. If I end up doing encryption and socket level send/recv by myself, that will be nightmare. Or is there any other tools can achieve that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mutual authentication doesn't require the two parties to have certificates issued by the same CA.

Comment: Yes, so how do you verify certificate in such case?

Comment: The server and the client configure their trusted anchors in their respective settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the certificates can not be validated and trusted for whatever reason, it makes sense not to use them at all then. TLS supports alternative authentication schemes including OpenPGP, pre-shared keys and one-time passwords. OpenSSL supports pre-shared keys, if memory serves, and there exist alternative libraries depending on the platform.